# What are the practical applications of the voxel data texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I have looked quite a bit at the capabilities of the voxel data texture.  I understand that it is "volume pixels" where it gets its name from.  It looks like they can use it some programs to take slices of images and reconstruct 3D models out of it like reconstructing MRI and CRT scans which is super cool.  It's seems like this could be such a powerful thing in terms of getting really cool effects because you can access the data of these "volume pixels" and do some really cool things with it.  I know it's used for smoke simulations.  Could you use it to do cool things with point density stuff like cloud creation and whatnot?  Based on my limited knowledge on it, it seems like there aren't a lot of practical effects you can use with this or it would be getting used more often.  What're your guys' thoughts?